# Lookup delimited values in a table in sql-server

Tags: sql-server

In a table A i have a column (varchar*30) city-id  with the value e.g. 1,2,3 or 2,4.
The description of the value is stored in another table B, e.g.
1 Amsterdam
2 The Hague
3 Maastricht 
4 Rotterdam

How must i join table A with table B to get the descriptions in one or maybe more rows?

Comment: This is by no means impossible but Is there a really good reason you can't just normalize your data structure?

Comment: **DON'T STORE DELIMITED VALUES IN TABLES!** You want to convert this data to use an additional table that has the primary key from your current table next to a _single_ city_id, where each record from the current table may have several records in the new table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming this is what you meant:

Table A:
id
-------
1
2
3

Table B:
id |  Place
-----------
1  | Amsterdam 
2  | The Hague
3  | Maastricht 
4  | Rotterdam

Keep id column in both tables as auto increment, and PK.
Then just do a simple inner join.

select * from A inner join B on (A.id = B.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way to deal with such scenarios is to have a normalized table as Collin. In case that can't be done here is the way to go about -

You would need to use a table-valued function to split the comma-seperated value. If you are having SQL-Server 2016, there is a built-in SPLIT_STRING function, if not you would need to create one as shown in this [link](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

```
create table dbo.sCity(
    CityId varchar(30)
);

create table dbo.sCityDescription(
    CityId              int
    ,CityDescription    varchar(30)
);

insert into dbo.sCity values
('1,2,3')
,('2,4');

insert into dbo.sCityDescription values
(1,'Amsterdam')
,(2,'The Hague')
,(3,'Maastricht')
,(4,'Rotterdam');


select  ctds.CityDescription
        ,sst.Value as 'CityId'
from    dbo.sCity ct
        cross apply dbo.SplitString(CityId,',') sst
        join dbo.sCityDescription ctds
            on sst.Value = ctds.CityId;
```